# Copy some items in the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I want to copy some data in the collection. For example the result of the such query;

```
  db.collection("test").find({tag: "ABC"});
```

which results as;

```
{"_id" : "1","tag" : "ABC"}
{"_id" : "2","tag" : "ABC"}
```

I want to copy these 2 items and create new items with new id.

How can I do it?

1.I think that I can do it by;

```
db.collection("test").find({"tag": "ABC"}).each(function(err, item) {
   //insert each item with a new id

}
```

But is there better way to copy the collections with query?

Clarification;

As a result I want to have;

```
{"_id" : "v1_1","tag" : "ABC"}
{"_id" : "v1_2","tag" : "ABC"}
{"_id" : "1","tag" : "ABC"}
{"_id" : "2","tag" : "ABC"}
```

Comment: Rather unclear what you want to do here; you want to copy some data, what data? Do you mean to copy to another collection?

Comment: no no. in the same collection. I want to copy the items in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of this solution :

```
db.collection("test").find({"tag": "ABC"}).each(function(err, items) {
    if(err) console.log("Error : " + err);
    if(items){
        db.collection("test").insert(items, function(err, items){
            if(err) console.log("Error: " + err);
            if(items) console.log("Data inserted successfully");
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know if there's a better solution than this.